# How to reset counter value at midnight in java?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I am writing functionality in Spring Boot to generate a unique sequence Number/ request count in a day. For this, I am creating and assigning value to a variable say Counter. To provide a unique sequence number to every request, how can I use multi-threading with Spring Boot? Is using a database table for this also mandatory?
How can I write logic to reset this counter value to zero every day at midnight?

Comment: maybe show some code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that counter is something that gets always increased and that's the way of guaranteeing uniqueness?

If so, there are two different questions:

1. How to use the counter in a multithreaded environment?

The answer to that is that there is no problem with that as long as the counter itself "is ready" to work in a multithreaded environment.

You can create a counter as a bean and inject it into a controller that will be an entry point:

```
@RestController // just to emphasize that its a controller
public class MyController {
   private final Counter counter;

   public MyController(Counter counter) {
      this.counter = counter;
   }
   @GetMapping
   public void foo() {
       counter.increase();
   }
}
```

The `foo` method can be called by multiple threads simultaneously.

In terms of implementation of the counter you might want to consider `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong` or `AtomicInteger` maybe. This class can work in a multithreaded environment. Alternatively, you can opt for a custom class with locks.

The point is that it's possible to do as long as the counter itself is designed to be called simultaneously from different threads.

2. Now the second question is how to reset the counter to zero every midnight

This can be done with Scheduling support for spring:

Create a job that will run every midnight, inject the counter and add a  `@Scheduled` method that will run at midnight and it will reset the counter.

```
@Component
public class MyCounterReseter {

   @Autowired
   private Counter counter;

   @Scheduled("0 0 * * *") // I haven't tested it but you get the idea
   public void resetCounter() {
      counter.reset(); // or call any other method depending on the actual counter implementation you'll choose
   }
}
```

Don't forget to annotate `@EnableScheduling` so that the `@Scheduled` annotation will be processed by Spring

In general, consider [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) for example to learn more about scheduling support in spring. There are many other tutorials of course.